# how can I achieve this result in a "partial" SQL join?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a partial join but can't get it right. I have part of it.

Given T1:

[image]

And Also T2:

[image]

I need to achieve the following T_new. I'm able to get 'B' and 'XX' but not 'A'. That is, where T2.ID = T1.ID but not the year.

[image]

I can do a right join to get 'B' and 'XX'

So for example,

```
select T2.ID, T2.year,
case when T1.ID is null then 'XX'
else 'B'
end as label
from T1
right join T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.year = T2.year
```

But that only gets me here:

[image]

How can I get the ones where IDs are the same but year is not (ID = 1 and year = 2005)?

FYI, in the end the table should have the same shape as T2. It's just looking up values in T1.

Comment: When you say "I'm able to get 'B' and 'XX' but not 'A'" do the letters represent the data being in only in `T1` (A) both tables (B) or only in `T2` (XX)?

Comment: A means the IDs match but not the year between T1 and T2. B is a match on both ID and year (inner join, for example). XX is no match on either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an assumption that you'll always want all the records from T2. So if that's true, then we can just `LEFT JOIN` T1 twice and do a `CASE` statement for the label. I also renamed `year` to `yr`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t.id
,t.yr
,label = CASE WHEN s.id = t.id AND s.yr = t.yr THEN 'B'
            WHEN r.id = t.id THEN 'A'
            WHEN r.id IS NULL THEN 'XX'
        END
FROM T2 t
LEFT JOIN T1 s ON s.id = t.id AND s.yr = t.yr
LEFT JOIN T1 r ON r.id = t.id
```

Comment: Nice, much simpler than my query. +1

Comment: Ah left join on T1 twice. I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting query because of the limited information available to distinguish rows not in T1 from the rows in T1 which match T2 by `id` alone but this is what I came up with - note I've replaced `year` with `yr` to avoid having to quote the field name as it's a reserved word:

```
-- The final outer 'select' takes the information from the first set of results but if
-- there's a label available from the second set (which has been left joined) use that label.
select first.id, first.yr, ifnull(second.label, first.label) label
from (
        -- Get all the rows from T2, where they match T1 on id and year
        -- give them label = 'B', all other rows not in T2 get assigned 'XX'
        select T2.id, T2.yr, if(T1.id is null, 'XX', 'B') label
        from T2 left join T1
          on T2.id = T1.id and T2.yr = T1.yr
     ) first

left join

     (
        -- Get all the rows in T2 where only the ID is the same as T1
        select distinct T2.id, T2.yr, 'A' label
        from T2 join T1 on T2.id = T1.id
        where T2.yr not in
          -- then exclude any years from T1 where the id is the same
          (select yr from T1 where T1.id = T2.id)
     ) second

on first.id = second.id and first.yr = second.yr
order by first.yr
```

Giving the result

| id | yr | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005 | A |
| 1 | 2006 | B |
| 1 | 2007 | B |
| 1 | 2008 | B |
| 10 | 2010 | XX |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sdgzaEF46VB9BwLzg3f4NP/1)

It's a nasty query and I have no idea how well it would perform with a larger data set. Fundamentally I think the structure of your model needs to change to make this query easier but without more information about what you are trying to achieve I can't begin to help with that.

Comment: After digital.aaron posted their answer I considered deleting mine but then I thought it might be interesting to others. When trying to answer this I was thinking about how to "overlay" sets through a `union` rather than joining, so I ended up writing a complicated query. If I'd thrown away the idea when it started to get difficult I may have come to a simpler solution - learn from my mistakes! :)